# How to create a Smart Field control with ValueHelp feld

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I need to implement a Smart Field control with Value Help in my form. I am getting json response from ODATA service. And I am setting it to a JSONModel. I have tried a sample code refering this [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield/code/SmartField.controller.js) but I don't know how to bindElement. Please refer this [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/ruzabek/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2):

SmartControls rely on OData! However, you are using a JSONModel! Also, as @matbtt mentioned you are binding a single field to an array, but you should do it the way he mentioned above... This [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bovuwazimo/edit?html,output) is the correction but still only with a JSONModel instead of an ODataModel. And [this one uses OData](https://jsbin.com/haqodeqope/edit?html,output) and works just fine.

Is there a specific reason why you call an OData Service and wrap the response into a JSONModel? Do you know how to use the ODataModel in UI5?

And thank you for using my single file template!

Answer (score 0):

As your data are contained in a named array you need adjust the binding as follows:

```
<smartField:SmartField value="{/TableCollection/0/AccountNo}" id="companyCode"/>
```

Comment: I need smart field with value help !!

Comment: The you should not ask why your binding is not working!? Furthermore you should add more information about your problem, are you using OData or not. If not, why are you then using Smart Field?!